# How to take a string with some specific length in java

Tags: java, string, io

I am new in java and working on some example of string. I am taking a number of String I need and then for each string I am specified some length which also a input from user. Once i get length integer I am trying to get same length of String. If it is exceed or less then I am throwing error. But I stuck how to get this.

In few places I am getting **java.util.InputMismatchException**
My Code :

```
package Test;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestInputString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         int Num = sc.nextInt();
         for(int i=0; i<Num; i++){
             int length = sc.nextInt();
             String str1 = sc.next();

         }
    }

}
```

My Output should be like this. 
Ouput :

```
No. of String - 3

Length : 4
String : ABCD

Length : 5
String : ABCDE

Length : 6
String : ABCDF
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of : `String str = sc.nextLine();`

Use this : `String str = sc.next();`